# A Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For:
$x^2 y'' +x y'+ \lambda y=0, y(1)=y(e)=0$

I found that with $m=\frac{1}{x}$ we can have the Sturm-Liouville equation $\frac{d}{d}[x y'] +\frac{\lambda y}{x}=0,$ since $x^2y''+xy'+\lambda y=0$ is Cauchy-Euler equation which on substitution $x=e^t$ reduces to $(D^2+\lambda )y=0$ where $D\equiv \frac{d}{dt}$.

But, if we assume the norm $||Y_n||_m=\sqrt{\int_{1}^{e} m(x) Y_m^2(x)dx},$ I don’t know how to calculate the normalized eigenfunctions for $\frac{ Φ_n(x) }{||Φ_n||_m }$ and if these eigenfunctions are orthogonal under the inner product $\int_{1}^{e} m(x)f(x)g(x)dx$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions come about from the solutions of the SLP. Starting with the differential equations, the solutions are:

$$ y(x) = A \cos (\sqrt \lambda \cdot \log x) +  B \sin (\sqrt \lambda \cdot \log x)$$

Now, applying the first boundary condition:

$$0 = y(1) = A \cos (0) +  B \sin (0) = A$$

Therefore, the maximal set of solutions is:

$$y(x) = B \sin (\sqrt \lambda \cdot \log x)$$

Applying the second boundary condition, we see:

$$0 = y(e) = B \sin (\sqrt \lambda)$$

In order for us to not have a trivial solution $(B = 0)$, we can assume otherwise and arrive at: 
$$0 = \sin (\sqrt \lambda)$$
This can only be true provided for some $k \in \mathbb Z$
$$\pi k = \sqrt \lambda$$
$$\lambda = (\pi k)^2$$

Therefore, the maximal set of eigenfunctions is countable with the sequence: 
$$\{ y_k(x) = \sin (\pi k \log x) \}_{k={-\infty}}^{\infty}$$

Therefore, to normalize, simply define: 
$$\left \{ \hat y_k(x) = \frac{y_k(x)}{||y_k||_{m}} \right \}_{k={-\infty}}^{\infty}$$

I'll assume you know how to calculate the $m$-norm of a function.

Comment: You did lose the logarithm in the solution formula, it should be $y_k(x)=\sin(k\pi\log x)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it